# Pageres does not work with php exec

Tags: php, apache, npm

I installed this npm module on my digitalocean droplet

https://github.com/sindresorhus/pageres

It works right if i access it with the terminal directly. But, if i access them with PHP via `exec()`, it loads, and loads, and loads...and my mysql server shutting down (or apache?) and i need to `sudo restart`.

Then i tried it with this:

```
exec('pageres http://google.com 2>&1', $output, $returnCode);
$output = implode(PHP_EOL, $output);
echo $output . ' ' . $returnCode;
```

And it loads for a long time, but then i become this message `Generated 82 screenshots from 1 url and 82 resolutions`. I loads the correct 82 images in my projekt, but I have not entered any other parameter for pageres (for other resolutions).

I have this same problem on local with xampp.

If i run `whoami` on the website with exec(), i become `www-data`, but if i run it on the terminal, i become `safeuser`. Is this important?

// Edit: I tried it with laravel 4 `SSH`, `whoami` returns `safeuser`, but it does not work